# Jenkins: How to disable DockerContainerWatchdog from running

Tags: jenkins

I've installed Docker plugin and was able to setup a test job to run on a slave container.
The test job is a basic loop with echo that runs for 15 minutes.
My problem is that the job never finishes. It runs for a few minutes and then the connection to the slave docker is lost and job gets stuck and fails.

After reading about this issue, I tried several suggested solutions, but it didn't help.
One of the things that can affect my issue is disabling DockerContainerWatchdog from running.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to disable DockerContainerWatchdog from running.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Boris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

Run the following code in Jenkins' Script Console:

```
System.setProperty("com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerContainerWatchdog.enabled", "false")
```

Please note: This will be active only until Jenkins' next restart.